# Any recommendation of dynamic forms builder with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Recently i have to find some form builder for my site user to create a form.
This is what i have found,

> http://www.berthou.com/us/2009/09/05/dynamic-forms-builder-with-jquery/.

This is just what kind of jquery plugin i want , but it is not in english, so are there any other similar plugin aviliable so far?

Thanks

Comment: You can try my plugin http://code.google.com/p/idealforms/. Not exactly what you're looking for but it might help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these.

http://www.jotform.com/

http://wufoo.com/examples/

I have personally used Wufoo. It is pretty good. However, you will need a paid subscription to use advanced features like Wizards and Paypal integration. You can give Jotform a try though.

P.S: These were mentioned in the link which you provided in your question. I am posting this assuming you missed those links.

Comment: That are good recommendation, and are there any these kind of program open -sourced? As i would like to put it in my program

Comment: Well, you can not consider them open source. You can create forms using these. Once you are finished creating forms, those websites will give you your form's HTML, CSS and Javascript source code to download.